# Unit test lack on internet connectivity

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, fetch, chai

### Background

I would like to use FetchMock and Chai/Mocha to write a unit test for a feature I've written.

I have a wrapper around fetch that causes it to return a response with a (specific) failed code if there's a network failure, instead of rejecting.

The code itself works. I can hand test it by bringing down the wifi on my machine by hand while the code is running.

I have reason to expect this code will be refactored, someday, by someone. So I would like some unit tests around it.

### The Question

How do I use Chai/Mocha, and any other tools (like fetchMock which I'm currently using) to create a test around that scenario?

I can't figure out how to fake a network failure from within a unit test.

Comment: How does the wrapper detect/determine there's a network failure?

Comment: generally your request module will handle a down network by either rejecting a promising, populating error in a callback, or throwing. All you would need to do is mock what your request module is doing.

Comment: So my wrapper runs 
`try{
   return await fetch(*stuff*);
}catch(e){
   return something;
}`

where previously fetch rejected @robertklep

Comment: It might be a bit hackish, but can't you get `fetchmock` to throw a deliberate exception?